# window.onbeforeunload, but for a frame?

Tags: javascript, frame, frameset, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to put up a warning message about leaving a webpage, but it is nested inside a frameset.

Apparently window.onbeforeunload triggers if I load the webpage as the root page in the browser, but doesn't trigger when loaded inside the frameset.

**Edit**: It doesn't work in Chrome 7 or Safari 5, but it works in Internet Explorer 8 and FireFox 3.6. Is there a fix/workaround so that I can get it working in Chrome 7 and/or Safari 5 as well?

What am I doing wrong?

This is what I tried:

```
function closePageWarning()
{
    return "Are you sure you want to leave this page?"
}

window.onbeforeunload = closePageWarning
```

Test documents:

### test1.html (page with unbeforeunload script)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript">
        function closePageWarning()
        {
            return "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
        }

        window.onbeforeunload = closePageWarning;
        </script>
        <a href="http://www.bitbucket.org">bitbucket</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

### test2.html (frameset)

```
<html>
    <frameset cols="20%, 80%">
        <frame name="menu" src="test3.html" />
        <frame name="content" src="test1.html" />
    </frameset>
</html>
```

### test3.html (menu, trigger change of frame with script)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a target="content" href="http://www.bitbucket.org">bitbucket</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

How to test:

- Load up test1.html in your browser, and click the link, notice you get the question
- Load up test2.html in your browser, click either link, notice you get no question

Tested in:

- Google Chrome 7.0.517.44 - doesn't work
- Internet Explorer 8.0.7600.16385 - **works**
- Safari 5.0.2 - doesn't work
- FireFox 3.6.12 - **works**

Comment: Strange, never heard of this. Can you confirm that the exact code works outside the frameset? In what browsers have you tested?

Comment: @Pekka: onbeforeunload is a Microsoft defacto standard, implemented in all major browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload.

Comment: @Eric no, I mean the behaviour that it doesn't work in an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a frame, `window` refers to the frame, which is a kind of window.  So `window.onbeforeunload` refers to an event of the window in the frame, which is not fired when the root page is unloaded.  You can refer to the root window by `window.top`, or to the direct parent window of the frame by `window.parent`.  However, these are not standard properties, so use them at your own peril!

Comment: Still, if he declares the `onbeforeunload` inside the child document, it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Seems like WebKit is the culprit here.

Comment: Note that I'm not unloading the whole window, just the single frame.

Comment: @Lasse: Sorry, I misunderstood.  I think you are right.  Looks like there are a couple of WebKit bugs around this feature.

Comment: Ok, I guess some support is better than no support. I'll try to find a different way for the other browsers.